# Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, onkeydown, onkeypress

I have one text input and one button (see below). How can I use JavaScript to **trigger the button's click event** when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed inside the text box?

There is already a different submit button on my current page, so I can't simply make the button a submit button. And, I *only* want the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to click this specific button if it is pressed from within this one text box, nothing else.

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

Comment: Important note for rookies like me: The key part of this question is if you already have a form on the page so already have a submit button. The jQuery answer is cross browser compatible and a good solution.

Comment: @JoshuaDance, already having a form/submit is not a trouble. A page can have many forms (but not nested), each having their own submit. Every field of each form will trigger only the submit of that form. As stated by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/156905/1178314).

Answer (score 1544, accepted):

In jQuery, the following would work:

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#id_of_button").click();
    }
});
```

```js
$("#pw").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#myButton").click();
    }
});

$("#myButton").click(function() {
  alert("Button code executed.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Username:<input id="username" type="text"><br>
Password:&nbsp;<input id="pw" type="password"><br>
<button id="myButton">Submit</button>
```

Or in plain JavaScript, the following would work:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_textbox")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("id_of_button").click();
    }
});
```

```js
document.getElementById("pw")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});

function buttonCode()
{
  alert("Button code executed.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Username:<input id="username" type="text"><br>
Password:&nbsp;<input id="pw" type="password"><br>
<button id="myButton" onclick="buttonCode()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: It is probably a better practice to query event.which than event.keyCode or event.charCode, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes

Comment: @William: As he's using `keyup`, and your link says *"`charCode` is never set in the `keydown` and `keyup` events. In these cases, `keyCode` is set instead."*, it doesn't matter. That said, though, I don't think `keyup` is the right event for the job (`keydown`, I would have thought; that's how a button behaves when it has focus, for instance).

Comment: `keydown` not `keyup` is the better event to use. Also, if you are using asp.net you will have to `return false` at the end to stop asp.net from still intercepting the event.

Comment: Problem with using `keydown` is that holding down enter will fire the event over and over again. if you attach to the `keyup` event, it will only fire once the key is released.

Comment: `$(this).click();` looks nicer, and might will work with selectors that match more than one element (ie: `$('.buttons')`)

Comment: I used $inputs = $('#foo,#bar'); $inputs.on('keydown', ...), and $inputs.off('keydown') when received an event to prevent auto-repeat, and return false to prevent wrong button being triggered.

Comment: I've tweaked your code adding `event.preventDefault();` before invoking `click();` function while my page has a form and I've switched `keyup` with `keypress` as it was the only working handler for me, anyways, thanks for neat piece of code!

Comment: This works for ff, chrome, ie in a asp.net app if you change it to keydown and add event.preventDefault() before the click() event. Hate that asp.net webforms app are so sensitive to this kind of crap.

Comment: @Hugo You can't use `$(this)` because the parent ID is that of the textbox, and the one you want to `click()` on is the button ID.

Comment: Why people hate jQuery so much? Any particular reason to discourage the use of jQuery?

Comment: To be fair, jQuery was pretty much synonymous with JS back when this answer was posted.  But now a lot of us who avoid jQuery altogether (because it's just a waste of kb when you're using something like React) feel annoyed when we search for answers to JS questions and often the first thing that comes up is a library we don't want to depend on.

Comment: @sohaiby: if OP was using jquery, he would ask about it. And if he was not using jquery, suggesting it is overkill for such a simple task. It is the same as asking how to merge strings in C++ and receiving an answer about using Qt's QString. Technically valid, but not what the question was asking for.

Comment: Please use `key` instead of `keyCode`. The latter is deprecated.

Comment: I voted up, but for some reason I had to use single quotes to make it work. Like this: document.getElementById('pw') and document.getElementById('id_of_button').click();

Comment: `event.keyCode` worked in windows and on mac systems for me. Thanks

Answer (score 437):

Then just code it in!

```
<input type = "text"
       id = "txtSearch" 
       onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"    
/>

<input type = "button"
       id = "btnSearch"
       value = "Search"
       onclick = "doSomething();"
/>
```

Comment: if you need to stop the form submission:onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();event.returnValue=false;event.cancel=true;}"

Comment: What about cross-browser compatibility? Does it work in all common browsers? (I see IE6 as common browser as it has still more than 5% of used browsers worldwide)

Comment: This worked for me due to fact that the inline method, instead of calling function with similar code in it, allows you to return false on the call and avoid postback. In my case the "click" method invokes a __doPostback async call and without the "return false;" would just reload the page.

Comment: @TimothyChung: Thanks immensely.  The rest of this page is great, but I got here via Google trying to figure out how to keep an "Enter" on a text field from triggering a postback _without_ using a <form> (which doesn't seem to work inside an asp:UpdatePanel).  This works.  (And it can be done inside a javascript function like kdenney's and probably in JQuery.)

Comment: I agree with Sam, this code with this inline JS-code is ugly as hell. You should always separate HTML and JavaScript codes.

Comment: Had to change `onkeydown` to `onkeypress` for it work in Chrome.

Comment: @Sam Never get your [wisdom from puppets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQduN315etk&t=19m32s). Pain leads to *fear*, and fear is the mind-killer. Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration. I will face my fear. I will permit it to pass over me and through me. And when it has gone past I will turn the inner eye to see its path. Where the fear has gone there will be nothing. Except maybe inline event handlers. So, yes, please separate your event handlers from your view/markup, as [this answer does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20064004/1028230). ;^)

Answer (score 186):

Figured this out:

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" Value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />

<script>
function searchKeyPress(e)
{
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: e = e || window.event; // shortest way to get event

Comment: Best plain JavaScript option.  Added JavaScript as an attribute in HTML is space-consuming, and jQuery is just jQuery (compatibility isn't guaranteed).  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: and if you return false inside the if, you can avoid the key from being processed further:

<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" Value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />

<script>
    function searchKeyPress(e)
    {
        // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

Answer (score 90):

Make the button a submit element, so it'll be automatic.

```
<input type = "submit"
       id = "btnSearch"
       value = "Search"
       onclick = "return doSomething();"
/>
```

Note that you'll need a `<form>` element containing the input fields to make this work (thanks Sergey Ilinsky).

It's not a good practice to redefine standard behaviour, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key should always call the submit button on a form.

Comment: Dudes! Read his entire question. There's already another submit button on the page, so this wouldn't work for him.

Comment: Fun fact, I recently tried to do this in SharePoint. However SharePoint already has a form that wraps around all your content, and any `<form>` tags are thrown out by the otherwise liberal HTML parser. So I do have to hijack keypresses or bust. (BTW, pressing Enter in SharePoint launches Edit mode for some reason. I guess the ribbon is using the same form.)

Comment: A `<button type="submit" onclick="return doSomething(this)">Value</button>` works to. The clue lies within the `return` keyword

Comment: @skybondsor - OTOH, [as mentioned by garrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156905/199364), OP was *incorrect* when he stated that limitation. It is entirely possible to have multiple forms on one page: just need to wrap the element inside its own form, and make sure that is *not inside* the other form on the page.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Of course! But we can both agree it was unclear from the original question whether multiple forms was a possibility. Another good reason to post as much of one's code as possible.

Answer (score 82):

Since no one has used `addEventListener` yet, here is my version. Given the elements:

```
<input type = "text" id = "txt" />
<input type = "button" id = "go" />
```

I would use the following:

```
var go = document.getElementById("go");
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");

txt.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
        go.click();
});
```

This allows you to change the event type and action separately while keeping the HTML clean.

> **Note** that it's probably worthwhile to make sure this is outside of a `<form>` because when I enclosed these elements in them pressing Enter submitted the form and reloaded the page. Took me a few blinks to discover.
>
> > **Addendum**: Thanks to a comment by @ruffin, I've added the missing event handler and a `preventDefault` to allow this code to (presumably) work inside a form as well. (I will get around to testing this, at which point I will remove the bracketed content.)

Comment: I really don't understand why the JQeuery answer has more upvotes. I cry for the webdevelopement community.

Comment: All you're really missing is an argument in your keypress handler and a `e.preventDefault()` to get it working with forms. See [my (new) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34441952/1028230).

Comment: unless you don't intend your users to actually enter any data, you should really do something like `if (event.keyCode == 13) { event.preventDefault();   go.click();} `

Comment: Using jQuery just for this tiny thing is sure useless. It also works much easily with CSP and takes less time to load. If you can, use this.

Comment: @David looking back almost a decade, do you still have the same vue? Or would you react differently, maybe in a little less angular fashion? :p

Answer (score 62):

In plain JavaScript,

```
if (document.layers) {
  document.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
}

document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
  var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
  if (keyCode == 13) {
    // For Enter.
    // Your function here.
  }
  if (keyCode == 27) {
    // For Escape.
    // Your function here.
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

I noticed that the reply is given in jQuery only, so I thought of giving something in plain JavaScript as well.

Comment: document.layers? Are you still supporting Netscape?!!

Comment: No you do not need to support Netscape.  http://blog.netscape.com/2007/12/28/end-of-support-for-netscape-web-browsers/

Comment: netscape.com doesn't even exists anymore (it redirects to aol.com) and yet there are still people supporting nescape, amazing.

Comment: `evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode` is equal to `evt.which || evt.keyCode`

Comment: @LeartS I'd bet that's because there are still people _using_ Netscape.

Comment: I don't understand why you check the availability of the `layers` feature in order to activate capturing of `Event.KEYDOWN`. What do those things have to do with each other? Test for `if (Event.KEYDOWN)` instead!

Comment: @LeartS Well technically https://isp.netscape.com/ still exists (though it's basically the same as https://www.compuserve.com/).

Answer (score 32):

## Use `keypress` and `event.key === "Enter"` with modern JS!

```
const textbox = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
textbox.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        document.getElementById("btnSearch").click();
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: looks like `keypress` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event)

Comment: @djvg Is `keydown` more suitable now?

Comment: @holydragon according to Mozilla's [`keypress` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event): "Warning: Since this event has been deprecated, you should use `beforeinput` or `keydown` instead."

Answer (score 23):

One basic trick you can use for this that I haven't seen fully mentioned.  If you want to do an ajax action, or some other work on Enter but don't want to actually submit a form you can do this:

```
<form onsubmit="Search();" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input type="text" id="searchCriteria" placeholder="Search Criteria"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="Search();" value="Search" id="searchBtn"/>
</form>
```

Setting action="javascript:void(0);" like this is a shortcut for preventing default behavior essentially.  In this case a method is called whether you hit enter or click the button and an ajax call is made to load some data.

Comment: This is a better solution for mobile device support. It automatically hides the keyboard on Android devices, and also iOS if you add `searchCriteria.blur();` to the `onsubmit`.

Comment: This won't work, as there is already another submit button in the page.

Comment: @JoseGómez, a page can have as many submit buttons as the dev wishes, being triggered by their corresponding fields only. It only takes to have distinct forms for each group of fields/submit. A page is not limited to a single form.

Comment: @Frederic: from the question I (mis?)understood that the other submit button was in the same form: _"There is already a different submit button on my current page, so I can't simply make the button a submit button."_

Comment: @JoseGómez, the question does not mandate to keep all in a single form. Many devs ignore they can put many forms in a single page. The way the OP has written its trouble's cause suggests he may be in that case. By example, lots of .Net webform devs believe html to be restricted to a single form per page, since .Net webform is restricted that way. But this is not a html restriction indeed.

Comment: This is a great answer since it allows custom actions yet avoids the need for a bunch of fancy override code.

Answer (score 18):

To trigger a search every time the enter key is pressed, use this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        $('#btnSearch').click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

**Try it:**

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" Value="Search"/>

<script>             
   window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById('txtSearch').onkeypress = function searchKeyPress(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('btnSearch').onclick =doSomething;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

## Short working pure JS

```
txtSearch.onkeydown= e => (e.key=="Enter") ? btnSearch.click() : 1
```

```js
txtSearch.onkeydown= e => (e.key=="Enter") ? btnSearch.click() : 1

function doSomething() {
  console.log('');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

Answer (score 14):

```
onkeydown="javascript:if (event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();}};"
```

This is just something I have from a somewhat recent project... I found it on the net, and I have no idea if there's a better way or not in plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 14):

In modern, undeprecated (without `keyCode` or `onkeydown`) Javascript:

```
<input onkeypress="if(event.key == 'Enter') {console.log('Test')}">
```

Comment: This is in my opinion the simplest answer that does the job.
In my use case, I upgraded it to onkeypress="inputKeyPressed(event)" and then handled the event.which parameter in the function itself. Enter key for example returns the event.which as 13.

Answer (score 13):

Although, I'm pretty sure that as long as there is only one field in the form and one submit button, hitting enter should submit the form, even if there is another form on the page.

You can then capture the form onsubmit with js and do whatever validation or callbacks you want.

Answer (score 13):

This is a solution for all the **[YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/)** lovers out there:

```
Y.on('keydown', function() {
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    Y.one("#id_of_button").simulate("click");
  }
}, '#id_of_textbox');
```

In this special case I did have better results using YUI for triggering DOM objects that have been injected with button functionality - but this is another story...

Answer (score 12):

In **Angular2**:

```
(keyup.enter)="doSomething()"
```

If you don't want some visual feedback in the button, it's a good design to not reference the button but rather directly invoke the controller.

Also, the id isn't needed - another NG2 way of separating between the view and the model.

Comment: Here's a question about further info on the keyup options: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32155887/435605

Answer (score 10):

This in-case you want also diable the enter button from Posting to server and execute the Js script.

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)
 {document.getElementById('btnSearch').click(); return false;}"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

Answer (score 9):

This **[onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange)** attempt is close, but misbehaves with respect to browser back then forward  (on Safari 4.0.5 and Firefox 3.6.3), so ultimately, I wouldn't recommend it.

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onchange="doSomething();" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

Comment: Should also mention that it triggers on unfocus.

Answer (score 9):

For jQuery mobile, I had to do:

```
$('#id_of_textbox').live("keyup", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == '13'){
    $('#id_of_button').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7. Is it still considered OK in jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 9):

Nobody noticed the html attibute "accesskey" which is available since a while.

This is a no javascript way to keyboard shortcuts stuffs.

[image: accesskey_browsers]

[The accesskey attributes shortcuts on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey)

Intented to be used like this. The html attribute itself is enough, howewer we can change the placeholder or other indicator depending of the browser and os. The script is a untested scratch approach to give an idea. You may want to use a browser library detector like the tiny [bowser](https://github.com/ded/bowser)

```js
let client = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    isLinux = client.indexOf("linux") > -1,
    isWin = client.indexOf("windows") > -1,
    isMac = client.indexOf("apple") > -1,
    isFirefox = client.indexOf("firefox") > -1,
    isWebkit = client.indexOf("webkit") > -1,
    isOpera = client.indexOf("opera") > -1,
    input = document.getElementById('guestInput');

if(isFirefox) {
   input.setAttribute("placeholder", "ALT+SHIFT+Z");
} else if (isWin) {
   input.setAttribute("placeholder", "ALT+Z");
} else if (isMac) {
  input.setAttribute("placeholder", "CTRL+ALT+Z");
} else if (isOpera) {
  input.setAttribute("placeholder", "SHIFT+ESCAPE->Z");
} else {'Point me to operate...'}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="guestInput" accesskey="z" placeholder="Acces shortcut:"></input>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the OP's question around the special case of key=ENTER

Comment: This answer misunderstands *accesskey*, which is a way to have a key *focus* on an element - after pressing the access key for the text area, one could then start typing into it. OP is asking for something quite different: a way to submit the contents of the current element.

Answer (score 8):

```
event.returnValue = false
```

Use it when handling the event or in the function your event handler calls.

It works in Internet Explorer and Opera at least.

Answer (score 8):

To add a completely plain JavaScript solution that addressed [@icedwater's issue with form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20064004/2), here's a complete solution *with `form`*.

> **NOTE:** This is for "modern browsers", including IE9+. The IE8 version isn't much more complicated, and can be [learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814964/1028230).

---

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rufwork/gm6h25th/1/

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="txt" />
        <input type="button" id="go" value="Click Me!" />
        <div id="outige"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

#### JavaScript

```
// The document.addEventListener replicates $(document).ready() for
// modern browsers (including IE9+), and is slightly more robust than `onload`.
// More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814964/1028230
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var go = document.getElementById("go"),
        txt = document.getElementById("txt"),
        outige = document.getElementById("outige");

    // Note that jQuery handles "empty" selections "for free".
    // Since we're plain JavaScripting it, we need to make sure this DOM exists first.
    if (txt && go)    {
        txt.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13)   {
                go.click();
                e.preventDefault(); // <<< Most important missing piece from icedwater
            }
        });

        go.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (outige) {
                outige.innerHTML += "Clicked!<br />";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

For those who may like brevity and modern js approach.

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {if (e.keyCode == 13) doSomething()});
```

where **input** is a variable containing your input element.

Answer (score 5):

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
 if (charCode == 13) {

        // Do something here
        printResult();
    }
};
```

Heres my two cents. I am working on an app for Windows 8 and want the button to register a click event when I press the Enter button. I am doing this in JS. I tried a couple of suggestions, but had issues. This works just fine.

Comment: Sort of overkill to place the event handler on the document. If you had a `charCode` of 13 anywhere else, you're firing off the `printResult()`.

Answer (score 5):

To do it with jQuery:

```
$("#txtSearch").on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode==13) {
        $("#btnSearch").get(0).click();
    }
});
```

To do it with normal JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("txtSearch").addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode==13) { 
        document.getElementById("#btnSearch").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: `getElementById` takes the id of the element without the hash.

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery, you can use `event.which==13`. If you have a `form`, you could use `$('#formid').submit()` (with the correct event listeners added to the submission of said form).

```js
$('#textfield').keyup(function(event){
   if(event.which==13){
       $('#submit').click();
   }
});
$('#submit').click(function(e){
   if($('#textfield').val().trim().length){
      alert("Submitted!");
   } else {
    alert("Field can not be empty!");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="textfield">
Enter Text:</label>
<input id="textfield" type="text">
<button id="submit">
Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

These day the `change` event is the way!

```
document.getElementById("txtSearch").addEventListener('change',
    () => document.getElementById("btnSearch").click()
);
```

Comment: change events fire when the user commits a value change to a form control. This may be done, for example, by clicking outside of the control or by using the Tab key to switch to a different control. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) I think a lot of people *wouldn't* want this behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

My reusable Vanilla JS solution. so you can change which button gets hit depending on what element/textbox is active.

```
 <input type="text" id="message" onkeypress="enterKeyHandler(event,'sendmessage')" />
 <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send"/>
```

---

```
function enterKeyHandler(e,button) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
        document.getElementById(button).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code in jQuery.

```
$("#txtSearch").keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode === 13 || e.key === 'Enter') 
    {
        $("#btnSearch").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have developed custom javascript to achieve this feature by just adding class

Example: `<button type="button" class="ctrl-p">Custom Print</button>`

Here Check it out [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/k6zL1q9t/)

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
    if(banner.hasClass("alt"))
    banner.removeClass("alt")
  else
    banner.addClass("alt")
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        
         if (e.ctrlKey) {
            $('[class*="ctrl-"]:not([data-ctrl])').each(function (idx, item) {
                var Key = $(item).prop('class').substr($(item).prop('class').indexOf('ctrl-') + 5, 1).toUpperCase();
                $(item).attr("data-ctrl", Key);
                $(item).append('<div class="tooltip fade top in tooltip-ctrl alter-info" role="tooltip" style="margin-top: -61px; display: block; visibility: visible;"><div class="tooltip-arrow" style="left: 49.5935%;"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"> CTRL + ' + Key + '</div></div>')
            });
        }
         
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.which != 17) {
            var Key = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
            if( $('.ctrl-'+Key).length == 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (!$('#divLoader').is(":visible"))
                    $('.ctrl-'+Key).click();
                console.log("You pressed ctrl + "+Key );
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        if(!e.ctrlKey ){
          $('[class*="ctrl-"]').removeAttr("data-ctrl");
            $(".tooltip-ctrl").remove();
        }
    })
});
```

```css
#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="ctrl-s" title="s">Change color</button><br/><br/>
  <span>Press CTRL+S to trigger click event of button</span>
</div>
```

-- or -- 
check out running example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58010042/6631280

> Note: on current logic, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score -4):

This also might help, a small JavaScript function, which works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function blank(a) { if(a.value == a.defaultValue) a.value = ""; }

function unblank(a) { if(a.value == "") a.value = a.defaultValue; }
</script> 
<input type="text" value="email goes here" onfocus="blank(this)" onblur="unblank(this)" />
```

I know this question is solved, but I just found something, which can be helpful for others.

Comment: The question was for triggering a button click with the enter key in a textbox. Your solution is for a "watermark" type of functionality.