# Set an image button to fire when enter key is pressed

Tags: html, defaultbutton

Obviously I know how to do this with DefaultButtons within an ASP.NET web form.  However, the way our client side developer wrote the code, he has a submit button done via javascript:

So the javascript is rendering the HTML.

```
<img id="submitBMI" onclick="quizCalc(); return false;" class="btnHover" src="Submit.gif">
```

Is there anyway to make this a DefaultButton?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is what you're after having the enter key pressed inside a textbox submit to the method quizCalc()?  If so, does it work in any of the different browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to have the quizCalc() method be called when, for example, the enter key is pressed in a textbox of that form, then you could just set the onsubmit handler of the form to call that method:

```
<form ... onsubmit="quizCalc(); return false;">
```

If you want a little more control on which input elements call the method then you could look at using onkeypress with a single handler onKeyPress(event), check out a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-button-click-with-javascript-on-enter-key-in-text-box)

**Update**

You could do what Jonathan says, but just remove the return false as that cancels the keypress from adding characters to the textbox.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e)
{
  var keyCode = document.all ? event.keyCode : e.which;
  if(keyCode == 13) quizCalc(); 
}
```

Comment: hmm that didn't seem to do it.

Comment: also, if you use the form onsubmit make sure you get rid of any onkeydown/onkeypress/onkeyup code relating to the [Enter] key (keyCode 13) as I believe the onsubmit makes more sense than capturing a key anywhere on the page, just my 2c

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you aren't using a js library, this will work if enter is pressed anywhere on the page:

```
document.onkeydown = function KeyDown(e)
{
  var keyCode = document.all ? event.keyCode : e.which;

  if(keyCode == 13) {
    quizCalc(); 
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using jquery in some parts of the page.  This didn't work, it didn't allow me to actually enter text into text boxes.

Comment: Silly me. You would actually want to enter data in your form first, wouldn't you? Updated.