# jquery - stop page reload

Tags: jquery

I have `Textbox` and `Button` (Next and Previous) displayed in `Lightbox`.
Currently my page is reloading upon clicking the Enter key.
I dont want this to happen.

What i want is, when i click the Enter key, the "Next" button should be clicked without page reload which resides back of lightbox.

I used the following code, but both `reload` and `click` on Next button are happening:

```
$("input").bind('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#nextbtn").trigger('click');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: see this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-button-click-with-javascript-on-enter-key-in-text-box

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your input button is type of button and not submit

```
<input type='button'>
```

Then try this one if keycode is 13 then it will call the nextbtn click event, then truen false so it wont load back.

```
$("input").bind('keyup', function(event){ 
  if(event.keyCode == 13){ 
      $("#nextbtn").click(); 
      return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put return false statement as soon as you trigger the Next button as follows:

```
$("input").bind('keyup', function(event){ 
    if(event.keyCode == 13){ 
        $("#nextbtn").trigger('click');
        return false; 
    } 
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your correctly, I think you just need to adjust your lightbox setup to use an iFrame.  If you are just using a standard DOM element, the form submission is going to trigger a page load.  The other way around that would be to use the jquery.form plugin to do AJAX form submissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else. As I understand the page is being reloaded because button is in the form and browser threads it as submit button. Please note, that this occures on `click` event, not on `keyup`. You can do two things:

First. Assign `click` event to the button that returns false.
Second. Change your input event to `keypress` instead of `keyup` and add one more line: `e.stopPropagation()`.