# Capturing the Enter key to cause a button click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to Capturing the Enter key to cause a button click

i have this javascript:

```
    function doClick(buttonName,e)
    {
        //the purpose of this function is to allow the enter key to 
        //point to the correct button to click.
        var key;

         if(window.event)
              key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
         else
              key = e.which;     //firefox

        if (key == 13)
        {
            //Get the button the user wants to have clicked
            var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
            if (btn != null)
            { //If we find the button click it
                btn.click();
                event.keyCode = 0
            }
        }
   }
```

with html

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Search" onClick="doSomeThing();" />
<input type="text" name="search" onKeyPress="doClick('submit',event)" />
```

this is work fine with IE browser but it didn't with Firefox,

Why ? can anybody fix this javascript code to work on all browsers.

thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is happening?  Is the method being called at all?

Comment: this link will help you definatly 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 7):

You should really not use inline event handlers:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('submit').onclick = doSomething;
   document.getElementById('search').onkeypress = function(e) {
       doClick('submit', e);
   };
};

function doClick(buttonName,e)
{
  //the purpose of this function is to allow the enter key to 
  //point to the correct button to click.
  var ev = e || window.event;
  var key = ev.keyCode;

  if (key == 13)
  {
     //Get the button the user wants to have clicked
     var btn = document.getElementById(buttonName);
     if (btn != null)
     { 
        //If we find the button click it
        btn.click();
        ev.preventDefault(); 
     }
  }
}
```

Your HTML should then look like this:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Search"/>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
```

Comment: The fact the OP is using event handler attributes is irrelevant to the question, and asserting that the OP shouldn't do so is dogmatic. It's perfectly valid to use event handler attributes and introduces no functional problems.

Comment: didn't work! i made alert box function for testing purposes.
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = getMsg();
but the alert box appears immediately when I open the page 
and when i click enter on IE but didn't work with Firefox also!

Comment: @Swell you need to assign the function reference, not the invocation return value: document.getElementById('submit').on click = getMsg;

Comment: yes this is work fine with Firefox but not with IE, I edited to work on IE, so can you edit your solution put this
        if(window.event)
        event.keyCode = 0
        else
        ev.preventDefault(); 
Instead of just
ev.preventDefault();
i want to set your solution  as a correct one but can you please edit it first.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using the `keydown` event instead for this particular case, since it simplifies key detection: you can use `keyCode` in all browsers. Also, you're passing in the ID of the button you want to click but then not using it, so I've changed that. Also, I've added a `return false` to prevent the default behaviour of pressing the enter key, (although this part won't have any effect in Opera: you'll need to suppress the `keypress` event instead in that browser):

```
function doClick(buttonId, e)
    {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
        // Get the button the user wants to have clicked
        var btn = document.getElementById(buttonId);
        if (btn)
        {
            btn.click();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Down but not up?  I've always found release to have a more intuitive feel.  Is this just your preference or is there an actual performance boost? (are some browsers better/faster with down than up?)

Comment: @cwallenpoole: The reason I went with `keydown` was to keep the same user experience as in the question: the OP was using `keypress`, which fires immediately after `keydown`. Also, it agrees with the native browser behaviour of submitting a form when the user presses the Enter key, which is triggered when the key is pressed rather than when it's released.

Comment: I forgot about the .click() method and that forms submit on enter down not enter up. Thanks, this really helped me out of a headache for the last hour.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a wrapper js framework like jQuery? It does all the cross-browser stuff for you. Just off the top of my head, this could work (still, you should probably verify):

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery(window).keyup( function(e){ 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      // handle click logic here
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

onKeydown

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('submit').click(); 
    return false;
}
```