# Focusing on applet

Tags: javascript, applet

HI

i have an applet included in my html page.
The applet consist of a button

```
Button play
```

i want this button to be triggered on click of a enter key, i mean it to be clicked every time i hit enter

i tried

```
if (document.layers) 
document.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN); 
document.onkeydown = function (evt) 
{ var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode; 
alert(keyCode); 
if (keyCode == 13) { 
document.playAndRecordAll.stopRecording();
 alert("hello"); 
return false;
 }
else return true; };
```

but  its not working, is there any thing internal in applet to do so?

Note: i found that if the focus is on the applet button then hitting space clicks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-button-click-with-javascript-on-enter-key-in-text-box), You can detect Enter press on a page,

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    //enter pressed
  }
});
```

Now, you need to create [`JSObject`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html) and need to access Button from Applet from javascript and simulate its click event;

Comment: @jigar - you mean i should call a java applet method from javascript or the other way?

Comment: yes  from javascript call a method that wraps up doClick of button