# How to press a button with Enter Key

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to bind click(from Button1's click event) event  in textbox When I pressed the enter key

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger button click with JavaScript on Enter key in Text Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-button-click-with-javascript-on-enter-key-in-text-box)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('#idoftextbox').keypress(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 13) {
        //enter has been pressed
    };
});
```

Comment: Some other Char Codes you may be interested in: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

Comment: I think jQuery normalizes `event.which`, so the `var code=...` line should not be needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" />

$("#textbox").bind('keypress', function(e)
{
   if(e.which == 13) 
   {
       // enter key was hit, do what you need to do here
   }
});
```

Since you didn't say what "textbox" means to you (as it can be textarea too), I assumed some dummy markup that I posted and then I bound the event to it.
I don't see the reason for binding an event to click and then bind event after that to the element.