# How to use JavaScript to simulate Enter key event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This question is quite different with [How do I use the Enter key as an event handler (javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931320/how-do-i-use-the-enter-key-as-an-event-handler-javascript) or [Prevent form submission on Enter key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

I just want to use a JavaScript function to replace Enter Key Event.

For example, now I am typing this string into a textarea

> "Hello world Hello world Hello world"

As you can see there are three "Hello world" in this string.

If I want to make this string to this effect

> "Hello world
>
> Hello world
>
> Hello world"

I should press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after every "Hello world".

Now this question is how to use JavaScript to replace the Enter Key Event? It means the user doesn't need to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and the scripts would do it automatically.

And also I hope that the scripts would cross different browsers.

Comment: is the user typing into a text area... or?

Comment: @mkoryak yes you r right : the user typing into a text area.

Comment: ok, now we are getting somewhere :) what have you tried?

Comment: @mkoryak I have tried createEvent but it doesn't work in Chrome.And other browsers may not support it.Have you got some good ideas?

Comment: do what simon says you should do. you do not want to actually create an enter event event. you want to add a newline in your textarea

Answer (score 2):

if you're in a `textarea` or a `pre`, you could split them using `\r\n` newline marker. Else, you could simply add a `<br>` tag.

```
var myString = "Hello world, Hello world, Hello world".split(',').join('\r\n');
$('textarea').text( myString );
```

Of course, you'll get the string via JS (`$('textarea').text()`), and I guess you'll want to use a RegExp inside the `split` method.

Example: http://jsbin.com/eqekir/1/edit

Comment: It is not the final effect that I want.I just want to use javascript to simulate keyboard event.And '\r\n' wouldn't be in added into the string. :-(

Comment: Hi, without more detail it's going to be hard to help you. I've made an example here so you can check out: http://jsbin.com/eqekir/1/edit Using `\r\n` work just fine as I showed you in my answer. I feel your problem now reside inside the logic you want to put in your script.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I have solved my problem with your answer.

Comment: Would you like to vote my question?!I don't know why it would be vote down.Besides,is there a way that I can use javascript to simulate a keyboard event? :-)

Comment: You can't use javascript to simulate a keyboard event in the way you meant it in your question. Although, you can trigger events, but those will only get catched by the `eventListener` you added via javascript. For example, in jQuery `$('a').trigger('click')` will not open the link, but it will trigger any event you added via `$('a').on('click', /* do something */ )`

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like

```
console.log("This is a \n new line");
```

That would make new line appear on a new line.  You could use a regular expression to separate the