# make use of the enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of urls(div) underneath an input field(div). I need the ability to come down in the list and than by hitting enter this will trigger some function designated to the url. This is the fidle: [the script](http://jsfiddle.net/yomoore/sjKgF/24/)

Over the last days I have tried to much things to explain, but in conclusion none of it worked. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This link maybe can help you. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-button-click-with-javascript-on-enter-key-in-text-box)

Comment: Hi @2GDev The link you provided is all about static elements. I now how to approach this. The urls in the fiddle are dynamic, I want to be able to use my keybord (arrow up/down) to highlight the url(which I have done with css) and than by pressing enter some function would have to be triggered.

Comment: i've tried this : 
// our document is ready 
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#searchbox").keyup(function(event){
          if(event.keyCode == 13){
//here you have to go to link
}
        });
With this you can handler the enter key but i've to find what function to call to display result...

Comment: I think getSearch(); but Im not sure since every function is entangled with other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line of code :

```
// set timers to do automatic hash checking and suggestions checking
setInterval(checkHash,500);
setInterval(checkSuggest,500);
```

Insert this :

```
$('#searchbox').keyup(
function (e){
    var curr = $('#suggest').find('.current');
    if (e.keyCode == 40) 
    {                                      
        if(curr.length)
        {
                $(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');
                $(curr).next().attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }
        else{
            $('#suggest li:first-child').attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }                    
    }
    if(e.keyCode==38)
    {                                        
        if(curr.length)
        {                            
                $(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');
                $(curr).prev().attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }
        else{
            $('#suggest li:last-child').attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }            
    }

    if(e.keyCode==13)
    {
        var search_terms = $('.current a').text();
        // perform a search with this text...
        doSearch(search_terms,true,false);
        //update the search textbox
        $('#searchbox').val(search_terms);
    }
})

    And don't forget to delete the previous code at the bottom...
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. But what do you mean with the phrase: ''with the text searched'' ?

Comment: if you run the script when you press enter on a result you got the search, but the search textbox contains the old search... so for a complete functionality you have to update the textbox with the new search terms...

Comment: Please look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yomoore/sjKgF/32/ Your code doesn't get the search after pressing enter...Maybe you misunderstood the question? Otherwise can you please be more clear?

Comment: you're right... but the problem is that the function is outside the document.ready and can't find the function doSearch... 
I've update my response to show you where you can put my code...

Comment: hahaha Im new at this so I forgive my self:) Thanks a lot for your time and effort, you have saved me a lot of headache.