# Search button - Twitter Search API

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm trying to create a button that takes a subject you've typed in and pulls the relevant tweets using the Twitter Search API.

I've seen something similar with the [jTwitter](http://custom-drupal.com/jquery-demo/jtwitter/) plugin, but I'm not sure on how to do it myself, and can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Here's the jQuery:

```
twitterUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?"+ q +"&rpp=1500&page=2&result_type=recent&callback=?";
       twitterList = $( "<ul />" );
       twitterFunction = function( data ) {
             $.each( data.results, function( i, item ) {
                   $( "<li />", { "text" : item.text } )
                        .appendTo( twitterList );
                   });
             $( "#twit" ).fadeOut( "fast", function(){
                   $( this ).empty()
                        .append( twitterList )
                        .fadeIn( "slow" );            
                   });
             };
$.getJSON( twitterUrl, twitterFunction );
```

And the HTML:

```
<article>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="q" placeholder="subject..." >
            <input type="button" id="start" value="start" >
        </form>
        <div id="twit"></div>
</article>
```

And a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyanNeil/q7jUB/3/).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the implementation @ http://jsfiddle.net/Jayendra/reVy7/10/

Customize the results handling.

Comment: Great, thank you. I should've known the value would be inside of q= instead of replacing it. Is there a way to get it to work if you type in the subject and press enter as well as clicking start?

Comment: you can handle it via keyup and checking enter code as 13 ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-button-click-with-javascript-on-enter-key-in-text-box

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when I try adding that jQuery snippet. The text in the input field disappears when I hit enter. Does it have to be implemented within the function for the JSON call? http://jsfiddle.net/RyanNeil/q7jUB/12/

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use  **[jQuery Twitter Search Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/twitter/)**