# How can I link this html button to the input type "text" so that when I press enter from the input type, the button is activated?

Tags: html, button

Here is the html code for the form:

```
<form>
 Input Twitter ID: <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid">  

<button type="button" onClick="getStatuses();">Get recent tweets</button>  

</form>
```

Currently the button activates getStatuses(). I want it so that when the user presses enter/return after inputting text, it also activates the button.
The input is used in getStatuses() and is referenced by the id of the input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onkeyup attribute and call a function:

JS:

```
function checkKey(e){
    var enterKey = 13;
    if (e.which == enterKey){
        getStatuses();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" onkeyup="checkKey(event)">
```

Comment: 13 is the keycode for the enter key. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/532/

Comment: just wondering if I am replacing anything in the code. Like am I changing 'event' for something else?

Comment: I added the code as you sent it and it wasn't working. Thanks for help btw

Comment: nothing, the text disappears, and the method i specified to run in the checkkey function doesn't execute.

Comment: what does the 'event' part mean?

Comment: That is passing in the current key that is pressed.