# Javascript enter key pressed event alternative for mobile site

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, events, mobile

I have a quickfeedback widget in my site which has only one textbox. When user presses enter key, the feedback is automatically sent using ajax. But this doesn't work in mobile devices like android, j2me and so on. Is there any alternative that works in both desktop and mobile? Adding a submit button is not acceptable for me.

Comment: Why isn't adding a submit button acceptable?

Comment: I think you should wrap it into a form and catch the onsubmit event. I guess that will be triggered when pressing 'enter' on the mobile device.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I want to keep it simple with just one text box only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just checked on Android, when you type something and press "Go" (enter alternative?) it will trigger an event and the key code is actually 13 so the same as Enter on desktop keyboards.

I'd suggest debugging the code and checking whether the submit is actually triggered but maybe the key code isn't always 13? Just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `onblur` in combination with enter key? If one can press enter, it'll work as is. If one can't, they'll just leave input and then `onblur` will do work.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `e.code=== "enter"` to `e.keyCode===13`**. It works for both desktop and mobile. The "Go" key on mobile has the same `keyCode` as "Enter" key.
Check your `e` object in `console.log()` in responsive mode (mobile), and you will understand the difference.

Comment: You actually didn't add anything new from [this 2013's above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16317389/14945696)?

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow so, missed that one. And I realised later that e.keycode is deprecated and I myself don't use it Hence `e.key === "Enter"` must be used, works perfectly for mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I made it with wrapping in a form add `onsubmit` then `preventDefault`. (`@submit.prevent` in Vue, actually.)

There doesn't really need to be an enter button, only just form and input.

```
    form.field.m-sm.px-md(@submit.prevent="onSearch")
      .control.has-icons-right
        input.input.is-rounded(type="search" placeholder="Search" v-model="q")
        span.icon.is-right
          fa(icon="search")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a exact answer for this... you need to recognize which is the key code of pressed button. Usually that is 13. And to activate this key in mobile you need to add `type="submit"` to that button. Code given down below with example...

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Trigger Button Click on Enter</h3>
<p>Press the "Enter" key inside the input field to trigger the button.</p>

<input id="myInput" value="Some text..">
<button id="myBtn" type="submit" onclick="javascript:alert('Hello World!')">Button</button>


</body>
</html>
```

1. Example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp)
2. Example on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Remember that you need to add `type="submit"` to that button...! Otherwise it wouldn't work properly in mobile devices...

Comment: The OP clearly said he has NO button. So this answer is useless.
`Adding a submit button is not acceptable for me.`
Not sure what is not clear about this.