# Why is this line of code necessary in clicking a button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

This solution was given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box) asking how to trigger an HTML button when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed in an input field.

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" Value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />

<script>
function searchKeyPress(e)
{
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
    if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
    }
}
</script>
```

Why is `if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }` nescecary? It appears to be checking if the argument didn't get passed correctly, why wouldn't it? Is this related to fixing browser compatibility issues?

Comment: Because of oldIE. But it's not necessary in this case, as you're passing `event` from the inline handler.

Comment: Short answer, yes, it's about browser compatibility.

Comment: as a note: one should avoid inline handlers. here is an article explaining some reasons why: http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because old IE versions are a horrible abomination that use a global variable `event` instead of a function argument like any sane developer would use.

For the same reason (oldIE developers being insane) you cannot use `.addEventListener()` in oldIE but have to use `.attachEvent()` instead.

Edit: Just saw that you are using an inline event and always pass the event. That way you will always have a valid event object in the first argument of your function. You do not need the additional code.

Comment: `onkeypress="some code here"`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener for how to do it properly.