# Can I trigger a link-button with a key?

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink, key

So I have this code on a page:

```
<a id="buy_now" class="btn_green_release" href="#"><span>BUY NOW!</span></a>
```

It's for a link button, not a standard input button.

What I want to do, is to have it triggered when I press a key. I've found something around here (link below) but it didn't work.

[Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Andrei

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
http://jsfiddle.net/2UCp7/[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UCp7/)

```
$("#buy_now").click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
    return false;
});

$('body').keyup(function(event){
    $("#buy_now").trigger('click');
    console.log('press any key');
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        console.log('press enter');
        $("#buy_now").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

NOTE 1: key 13 is for ENTER

NOTE 2 : I delegate the click in a function

NOTE 3 : better to use preventDefault instead of return false !

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and it's actually simple:

```
$('body').keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
     document.getElementById('buy_now').click();
}});
```

It works. :)

'ndrei