# How to get enter key to submit form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Now before you say there is an answer here, I have tried a couple and none worked out, for example this one: 
[Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

I have this little password protected website which can only be accessed by entering the password page. If I click submit when the password is wrong a message box will appear and if I click enter the page reloads with a slightly different address. Even when the password is right the page will still not reload.

Here is the website:
http://bodokh.co.nf/

HTML:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFBD">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"><form name="password1"><div align="center"><center><p><strong>Enter password: </strong><input
      type="text" name="password2" size="15"><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="submitentry();"></p>
      </center></div>
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function max(which) {
    return (pass[Math.ceil(which) + (3 & 15)].substring(0, 1))
}

function testit(input) {
    temp = numletter.indexOf(input)
    var temp2 = temp ^ parseInt(pass[phase1 - 1 + (1 | 3)].substring(0, 2))
    temp2 = numletter.substring(temp2, temp2 + 1)
    return (temp2)
}


function submitentry() {
    t3 = ''
    verification = document.password1.password2.value
    phase1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()) - 6 + (2 << 2)
    var indicate = true
    for (i = (1 & 2); i < window.max(Math.LOG10E); i++)
        t3 += testit(verification.charAt(i))
    for (i = (1 & 2); i < lim; i++) {
        if (t3.charAt(i) != pass[phase1 + Math.round(Math.sin(Math.PI / 2) - 1)].charAt(i))
            indicate = false
    }
    if (verification.length != window.max(Math.LOG10E))
        indicate = false
    if (indicate)
        window.location = verification + extension
    else
        alert("Invalid password. Please try again")
}
```

Comment: Try making a jsfiddle of the problem.  Its more concise and you may just end up answering your own question/

Comment: Please post your code here, so that the question will remain valid once you fix your web site.

Comment: You should use `return false` to not submit the form with php or whatever server side language

Comment: Instead of using an `onclick` in the submit button, use `onsubmit` in the form.

Comment: The enter key already is trying to submit your form. You have to handle the submit event the same way you're handling the click event for the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a consistent and reliable way to run `submitentry` on form submission you should use

```
<form onsubmit="submitentry();">
    ...
</form>
```

instead of

```
 <input ... onClick="submitentry();">
```

Comment: Now that is strange. What did you do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `submitentry()` from the submit button's `onclick` handler, call it from the form's `onsubmit` handler:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFBD">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"><form name="password1" onsubmit="return submitentry();"><div align="center"><center><p><strong>Enter password: </strong><input
      type="text" name="password2" size="15"><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit"></p>
      </center></div>
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the submission function should return `false` to prevent normal form submission:

```
function submitentry() {
    t3 = '';
    verification = document.password1.password2.value;
    phase1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()) - 6 + (2 << 2);
    var indicate = true;
    for (i = (1 & 2); i < window.max(Math.LOG10E); i++) {
        t3 += testit(verification.charAt(i));
    }
    for (i = (1 & 2); i < lim; i++) {
        if (t3.charAt(i) != pass[phase1 + Math.round(Math.sin(Math.PI / 2) - 1)].charAt(i)) {
            indicate = false;
        }
    }
    if (verification.length != window.max(Math.LOG10E)) {
        indicate = false;
    }
    if (indicate) {
        window.location = verification + extension
    } else {
        alert("Invalid password. Please try again");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but for some reason no matter what i attempt to do it just won't let me submit with the enter button. Thanks anyways though for your time.