# JavaScript: Saving/Loading cookies using HTML documents for a website

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

For school work I need to use JavaScript to Save and read a cookie. The code for setting the cookie is all good, I got it from w3Schools (I know it's a terrible guide apparently). My problem is getting it to work with HTML/notepad using the "path" thing going on.

When the webpage loads a function called checkcookie checks if the cookie exists, if it doesn't, it asks the user to enter their name and then saves a cookie for later. If a cookie already exists, it displays a greeting message :). So far, I have made the functions work on the example running interface thing that you can access on w3schools. However, I recently tried setting them up using HTML documents, and the cookies don't seem to save properly. I open a NotePad document, paste the code, save as HTML, and open with Google Chrome. The pop-up asks for my name, I enter, but when I reload, the pop-up asks for my name again, and again, and so on. Here is the page I got the functions from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

I think I need to sort out a path for the cookie, or something, I looked at this webpage for more info http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html but I still don't understand.

Why does this not work? Should I set the path to the file directory which the webpage's html documents are saved in? Why does it work in the w3schools TryIt system but not with raw HTML documents?

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var title = cname + "=";
    var cookie_array = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<cookie_array.length; i++) {
        var check = cookie_array[i];
        while (check.charAt(0)==' ') check = check.substring(1);
        if (check.indexOf(title) != -1) {
            return check.substring(title.length, check.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var name=getCookie("name");
    if (name != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + name);
    } else {
       name = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (name != null && name != "") {
           setCookie("name", name, 30);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need a web server to test cookies. You could use Apache other some other web server for that purpose. http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi  Once you're hosting your web page, you can use for example Chrome the view your cookies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201564/javascrip-cookie-save-form/27202745#27202745

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as mentioned by jyrkim is a webserver thing