# Enter Key not working in button

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using button key for my project but this is not work when i push Enter Key.
why 'enter key' not working in this `form`?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" >
<input type="button" >
</form>
```

how this is work with javascript, plz help me

i will not sue `type="submit"`

Comment: Why do you not want `type="submit"`?

Comment: That text input needs a label. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: You wanted to know why, and Oriol has told you.

Comment: thack for your answer

i'm find if:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want [implicit submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission):

> A [`form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) element's **default button** is the first [submit
>   button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-submit-button) in  [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#tree-order) whose [form owner](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-owner) is that
>   [`form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) element.
>
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly
>   (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text
>   field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a
>   form whose [default button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#default-button) has a defined [activation behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#activation-behavior)
>   must cause the user agent to [run synthetic click activation steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#run-synthetic-click-activation-steps)
>   on that [default button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#default-button).

Therefore, the button must be a [submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-submit-button), not a [button in button state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type-button-state):

```
<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an `<input type="submit">` is what you want :)

Comment: :) no i'm need use type="button"

Comment: @sia, I don't know how to do that. If you need a button, a `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` does the same thing, but it's not `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(form).on('submit', function{
  //do whatever you want...
})
```

```html
<form action="raftel">
<input name="name" type="text"/>
<input name="password" type="password"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```