# Search using enter key and search button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I'm using the following code and it works fine by clicking on the search button. But how can I also search using the enter key?

Code:

```js
<script>
function mySearch() {
  var text = document.getElementById('strSearchText').value;
  var url = "privatelink=" + text;

  window.open(url,'_blank');
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
button:hover {color:red;}
.rounded-corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    white-space:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 50%;
}
.smallbutton {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    white-space:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 20%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<br>
<input type="text" size="25" tabindex="1" value="" id="strSearchText">&nbsp;
<button class="smallbutton" onclick="mySearch();"><span style="DISPLAY: inline-block">Search</span></button>
```

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Comment: please check the tags before using them, hover your mouse on [box], it's not what you think. Please remove that.

Comment: Apologies it was an accident. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stick it in a form, and it does that by default

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" size="25" tabindex="1" value="" id="strSearchText">
    <button class="smallbutton">
        <span style="display: inline-block">Search</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

and then

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform')

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('strSearchText').value;
  var url  = "privatelink=" + text;

  window.open(url,'_blank');
}, false);
```

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind. Is it possible searching from three different links? like under "Var URL = 3 links"?

Comment: Not while redirecting, you would have to write custom serverside scripts that scrape those URL's and return the contents etc.

Comment: Thanks very much Adeneo. Will look into that soon.