# What are the options for (keyup) in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup, angular

The following works great when the **enter** key is released. **What other options are available for the `keyup` in addition to `keyup.enter`?**

```
<input #inputstring (keyup.enter)="doSomething(inputstring.value)"/>
```

Comment: Maybe this could give you a hint https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/523, it's quite old though.

Answer (score 62):

These are the options currently documented in the tests: ctrl, shift, enter and escape. These are some valid examples of key bindings:

```
keydown.control.shift.enter
keydown.control.esc
```

You can track this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c7572ac1f9bbda59ba301dd330e6f64faf91b9e1/modules/angular2/test/render/dom/events/key_events_spec.ts) while no official docs exist, but they should be out soon.

Comment: Wow, this answer was given when Angular was in its 20th alpha and it still works today.

Comment: Related documentation https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter

Comment: [New link for Angular 9](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.0.x/packages/platform-browser/test/dom/events/key_events_spec.ts)

Comment: This still works today with Angular 12, but it's important to note that **order matters** for the multi-key combos. `keydown.shift.enter` works, but `keydown.enter.shift` does not.

Answer (score 34):

I was searching for a way to bind to multiple key events - specifically, Shift+Enter - but couldn't find any good resources online. But after logging the keydown binding

```
<textarea (keydown)="onKeydownEvent($event)"></textarea>
```

I discovered that the keyboard event provided all of the information I needed to detect Shift+Enter. Turns out that `$event` returns a fairly detailed [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

```
onKeydownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
   if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey) {
       // On 'Shift+Enter' do this.......
   }
}
```

There also flags for the CtrlKey, AltKey, and MetaKey (i.e. Command key on Mac).

No need for the KeyEventsPlugin, JQuery, or a pure JS binding.

Answer (score 26):

Have hit the same problem today.

These are poorly documented, an open issue exist.

Some for ***keyup***, like space:

```
<input (keyup.space)="doSomething()">
<input (keyup.spacebar)="doSomething()">
```

Some for ***keydown***
(may work for keyup too):

```
<input (keydown.enter)="...">
<input (keydown.a)="...">
<input (keydown.esc)="...">
<input (keydown.alt)="...">
<input (keydown.shift.esc)="...">
<input (keydown.shift.arrowdown)="...">
<input (keydown.f4)="...">
```

All above are from below links:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18870
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8273
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/events/key_events.ts
https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/

Answer (score 13):

This file give you some more hints, for example, keydown.up doesn't work you need keydown.arrowup:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/630d93150a58581a0d474ebf1befb5d09b6813c5/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.dart

Answer (score 13):

you can add keyup event like this

```
template: `
  <input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
  <p>{{values}}</p>
`
```

in Component, code some like below

```
export class KeyUpComponent_v1 {
  values = '';

  onKey(event:any) { // without type info
    this.values += event.target.value + ' | ';
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers. The keyup event is not fired if i type number in the input field. What can we do for that ?

Answer (score 7):

The `keyCode` is deprecated you can use `key` property in the `KeyboardEvent`

```
<textarea (keydown)=onKeydownEvent($event)></textarea>
```

Typescript:

```
onKeydownEvent($event: KeyboardEvent){

    // you can use the following for checking enter key pressed or not
    if ($event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log($event.key); // Enter
    }


    if ($event.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey) {
           //This is 'Shift+Enter' 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your keyup event is outside the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd> bracket, just use @Md Ayub Ali Sarker's guide. The only keyup pseudo-event mentioned here in angular docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html is <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. There are no keyup pseudo-events for number keys and alphabets yet.

Comment: Sorry, Robert. I had no issues navigating to Angular docs using the link. It works.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Probably the issue was on my side. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

One like with events

```
(keydown)="$event.keyCode != 32 ? $event:$event.preventDefault()"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the app.component.html file
*Note: Have the form field above table tag*

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($any($event.target).value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
```

In the app.component.ts file

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```