# Angular: Mat-card keyboard navigation

Tags: angular-material, accessibility, keyboard-events

I am trying to make a mat-card navigable from the keyboard. Right now, when pressing `tab` the element is focused however the redirect event (should be the same as the click event) isn't triggered when pressing `enter`.

I've tried `keydown.enter` and `onKeyDown` (from a11y package) but no success so far.

**HTML**

```
<mat-card role="group" (click)="addQueryParam(group.name)" (keydown.enter)="addQueryParam(group.name)" class="mat-elevation-z0"
            [ngClass]="'background-'+index" (mouseout)="mouseOver=false"
    (mouseover)="mouseOver=true" style="padding: none; margin: 5px">
```

**Typescript**

```
  addQueryParam(groupName) {
    this.router.navigate(['/data'], { queryParams: { ['groups.title']: groupName }, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
  }
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

TIA,
Isabela

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you two things:

1. try using `(keyup.enter)=...`. I used it a couple of times and it worked well
2. If that doesn't work try using `(keyup)` or `(keydown)` and in your function check if the key code is 13 (enter key code), something like this:

**HTML**

```
<mat-card role="group" (click)="addQueryParam(group.name)" (keydown)="addQueryParam($event, group.name)" class="mat-elevation-z0"
            [ngClass]="'background-'+index" (mouseout)="mouseOver=false"
    (mouseover)="mouseOver=true" style="padding: none; margin: 5px">
```

**Typescript:**

```
addQueryParam($event, groupName) {
if($event.keyCode === 13){
    this.router.navigate(['/data'], { queryParams: ...);
 }
}
```

If i remember correctly you can check the type of the event in a field like `event.type`, or something like that.

Additionally **check this discussion out**, because theese functions are not well documented, and here you can find som infos :
[What are the options for (keyup) in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155887/what-are-the-options-for-keyup-in-angular2)

### **EDIT**

I also found this very useful article: https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/angular-pseudo-events-d4e7f89247ee