# Javascript Reload Function

Tags: javascript, html

In my html website I have a random number function:

```
   <script>
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomnumber;
   </script>
```

I would like to add a "reload" button that changes the random number generated, without reloading the page. Is there any way to do this besides the location reload?

Comment: Put the code inside a function and bind that function to the button click event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are going to repeat a process, you should use functions.
Your calculation is right. You just need to put it inside a function and call it in case of clicking the button.

```js
  function changeRandom(){
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomnumber;
  }
changeRandom();
```

```html
<div id="random">
</div>
<button onclick='changeRandom()'>Click</button>
```