# Javascript trigger button by pressing Enter without attaching it to the FormID

Tags: javascript, button, razor

## What I have

I have a simple view in my .cshtml file which uses the form

```
                      //actionName  //controller //method         //htmlAttributes
@using (Html.BeginForm("TableName", "Data",      FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmName" }))
{
    //combobox with id
    //button with id
}
```

I was able to implement triggering the button with Enter key by using answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box) as a basis.

```
$('#frmName').on('keypress', function (e) {
  sender = event || window.event;
  var hasfocus = $('#btnGo').is(':focus') || false;
  if (sender.keyCode == 13 && !hasfocus) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#btnGo').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

In above scenario, everything works as intended.

## What I need

I recently found that this particular view will not be using the form. As a result, I wanted to adapt my javascript code to separate it from the frmName. However, it proved to be trickier than I anticipated.

## What I tried

I tried replacing the formID with the button ID

```
$('#btnGo').on('keypress', function (e) {
  sender = event || window.event;
  var hasfocus = $('#btnGo').is(':focus') || false;
  if (sender.keyCode == 13 && !hasfocus) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#btnGo').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

I tried implementing something similar to accepted answer of the thread mentioned above.

```
document.getElementById("cbID")
.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (event.keyCode == 13 || $('#btnGo').is(':focus')) {
      document.getElementById("btnGo").click();
   }
});
```

In both cases, when I select a value from the combobox and press enter key, an unexpected error pops up

[image: Result of attempts above]

**Can you please point me in the right direction how I can attach Enter to button while separating it from my FormID?** (Preferably, without altering my initial javascript code too much, but I'm flexible to suggestions)

## Edit

After testing in different browsers(IE, Chrome, FF) for debugging purposes, I got the following results:

- Initial scenario works as intended in all 3 browsers
- My attempts inside Chrome leads to an error inside the browser instead of intended error checker
- My attempts inside FF leads so asking for my credentials, which I am hesitant to give

Honestly, I am more interested now in why pressing Enter leads me to some kind of file saving and options provided in my picture. The question itself is still relevant though.

Comment: Try in  chrome/firefox and inspect the browser console.

Comment: @Shyju Unfortunately, the customer only uses IE, so other browsers are out of option here...

Comment: For your debugging, can't you test with other browsers ? Just don't tell the customer that you used a non IE browser to fix the issue

Comment: @Shyju I have already tested in other browsers for pure debugging. However, in Chrome, everything proceeds with a normal logic, while Firefox keeps asking for credentials, which I am hesitant to ask. As a result, I do not understand, what is so particular about IE, that the same action provides the result from the picture. Mind you, My initial scenario works as intended in all browsers.