# Onclick and Enter key script

Tags: javascript, html

How can I have the same action when I press the Enter key as if I click the button? When I press the Enter key, I want it to run the same script as when I do the "onclick" event.

```
<button type="button" value="Login" class="btn green uppercase" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">Login</button>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Comment: That might be the case but if you´re not good with javascripts and dont want to waste hours of trying to play around without the result you want it is faster to ask here, right. Not all things are obvious for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    formhash(this.form, this.form.password);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for customized it for me Chris!