# onclick Build Event to Press Function Key on Editable Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's been years since I coded anything, and even then it was more of a hobby than a profession so you know my level of expertise on the subject at hand.

I have a button, and a field. Button is just an image label for a field which you can type in, but I want to build an "onclick event" that presses the F4 key on ElementID f0. Which is the Element ID of the Field that is editable.

I have a feeling I'm not explaining myself very well.

So I've attached a [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei0hH.jpg)

The button is Customer Name, so when they click on that, I want to press F4 on the field next to it which brings up another screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why F4? Is that how users move to another screen?

Comment: F4 is "Prompt" on the background program, it's a screen scraper basically and i have an AS400 behind it.

Comment: Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programatically) you are looking for keycode 115 (F4) and you want to programmatically execute that code in the click event callback of your input fields.

Comment: I found this post [Trigger button Click...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-butto‌​n-click-with-javascr‌​ipt-on-the-enter-key‌​-in-a-text-box) and modified the code. But it's still not working.

Comment: I found a way to do it. Stupid simple... Step 1, SelectRow = 8; Step 2 SelectCol = 13, Step 3 SendRequest ('04');

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH60K.jpg);
After reviewing a few links found [Here](http://esdi.excelsystems.com/iseries400apps/KB_TASK.pgm?TSK=14963) and also KB Article 15250 on the same site, and being on the phone with tech support for 55 minutes while he gave me a crash course on how to do a bunch of cool stuff!!