# .click() doesn't work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I guess .click function comes from jquery but I saw it in [pure js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box) too so I hope I can use it in my react code too. The event where I want to use it looks like

```
 keyUpFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log("blya");
        document.getElementsByClassName('button').click();
    };
}
...
<input onChange={this.updateMessage} onKeyUp={this.keyUpFunction} value={this.state.message} type='text' placeholder="Message" />
<button className="button"  onClick={this.submitMessage} >Submit Message</button>
```

The idea is after writing message I will push enter, onKeyUp will get it go to event handler and run `getElementByClassName().click()` and submit the message(run onClick). If I am wrong and I can't use click in react how can I implement it? both console.logs are working correctlly so the problem is in click()(I guess)

And here is the [whole code](https://jsfiddle.net/ArmenSan/05s1mz86/)

Comment: my question is about click() function not about getElementByClassName should I change something in my question ?

Comment: instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('button').click();` why not calling that function directly by `this.submitMessage()`, it will call that function and perform the task that you want to do

Comment: btw if you use `document.getElementById('button').click();` and define the `id ='button'` on button element it will work :) don't know why `className` is not working.

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan: You've said it doesn't work. The linked question's answers explain why it doesn't work: There is no `click` on the **collection** of elements returned by `getElementsByClassName`, note the plural; it's on individual elements. Hence my comment above about `querySelector`, which returns an element (the first one that matches).

Comment: @MayankShukla it doesn't work too. I am getting this error
Cannot read property 'submitMessage' of undefined
    at keyUpFunction

Comment: @MayankShukla is it good practice to use getElementById in react more then ones ?

Comment: i think, you forgot to bind the `keyUpFunction` because of that you are getting the error, bind that method in the constructor, it will work :), it is not a good practice to use `getElementById` not even once, try to avoid all the direct dom interaction.

Comment: @MayankShukla yea you where right!

Comment: @MayankShukla but I steal got this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: why you are using that, call that function directly by `this.submitMessage()` in place of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three separate problems here.

1. You're trying to call `click` on the result of `getElementsByClassName`. That [returns a **collection** of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method), not just one element. The `click` function exists on elements, not collections of them.
2. Calling that `click` function on the button will not trigger React's `onClick` handler.*
3. Working indirectly through the DOM is fundamentally not how you do things in React. (And it's poor practice in non-React code too.)

Instead, just call `this.submitMessage` from your `keyup` handler:

```
keyUpFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log("blya");
        this.submitMessage(event); // ****
    };
}
```

Simplified example:

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.doSomething = e => {
      console.log("Do something");
    };
    this.keyup = e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.doSomething(e);
      }
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input className="button" type="text" onKeyUp={this.keyup} />
        <input type="button" onClick={this.doSomething} value="Click Me" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Input />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

---

* Proof of Issue #2 above, in case others are unsure (like me, until I tried it):

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.doSomething = e => {
      console.log("Do something");
    };
    this.keyup = e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log("Calling `click`");
        document.querySelector(".button").click();
      }
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input className="button" type="text" onKeyUp={this.keyup} />
        <input type="button" onClick={this.doSomething} value="Click Me" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Input />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```