# Onclick event + Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, onclick

i have a really simple login script on a website, it uses just 1 simple password, and it does just fine what i need from it. thing is, it only works when clicking the "LOGIN" word. what i need it to do is to also work when pressing the Enter key. here´s the code:

```
<div style="background-image:url(images/IMG_Log_In_teste.jpg);width:1490px;height:243px;color:black;font-size:20px;" >
        <br></br>
        <a href="areaclienteOLD.html" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">
        <div class="cities">
            <font color="white">                            
                LOGIN
            </font>
        </div>
        </a><br></br>
        <input id='PASSWORD' type='PASSWORD'  />
        <a href="areaclienteOLD.html" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()"></a><br></br>
        <script>
            function validatePass(){
            if(document.getElementById('PASSWORD').value == 'pkmass1725'){
            return true;
                }else{
            alert('Password errada! Tente de novo.');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>                       
    </div>
```

i already tried adding input types and other things but nothing makes it work :(

UPDATE:

meanwhile i changed the code to this:

```
<div style="background:blue;width:1490px;height:243px;color:black;font-size:20px;" >
        <a href="areaclienteOLD.html" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">
        <div class="cities">
            <font color="white">                            
                LOGIN
            </font>
        </div>
        </a>
        <input id='PASSWORD' type='PASSWORD'  onkeydown="javascript:return validatePass()"/>
        <a href="areaclienteOLD.html" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()"></a>
        <script>
            function validatePass(){
            if(document.getElementById('PASSWORD').value == 'pkmass1725'){
            return true;
                }else{
            alert('Password errada! Tente de novo.');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>   

        <script>
            document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13)
                validatePass();
            };
        </script>

    </div>
```

but now whatever key is pressed it performs validation, so its not even possible to enter the password... i´m still missing something here

Comment: Just look for same already answered questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 2):

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        validatePass();
};
```

Comment: this is almost perfect, the only question is if the password is right than it doesn´t happen anything

Comment: @questionador Are you using a form to send the data? If so, you have to use javascript to submit it too.

Comment: @questionador If the password is right, `validatePass` just returns `true`. What do you expect to happen? And I just realized that your function is called in the anchors `onclick` so my question about the form was kind of stupid...

Comment: @schroffl in the function i use, when i click on the login button it validates the password and directs me to another page, it´s a rudimentary kind of login, i know. what i pretend is, after entering the password, the enter key having the same effect that clicking the Login button does

Comment: @questionador In your `onkeydown` handler you have to click the anchor. Get a reference to your element (e.g. via its id) and call `element.click()`. Also: As @YongQuan said, it's better to use `addEventListener` instead of directly assigning to the `onkeydown` property of an element.

Comment: sorry @schroffl i didn´t get it... like i have on:

onclick="javascript:return validatePass()"

but using onkeydown instead of onclick?

Comment: @questionador No, you leave your `onclick` on your login button. But in your script you add an event-listener for the `keydown` event where you simulate a click on the button (via the `click` method of the `a` element). You won't even have to call `validatePass` in your `keydown` listener, because the button itself will do it when clicked. And just a sidenote: Please never validate passwords on the client side (I assume this is just for learning).

Answer (score 1):

Attach it to document:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if (document.getElementById('PASSWORD').value === '') return;
    if (e.which === 13) validatePass();
    // e.which === 13 means enter key is pressed.
});
```

Attach it to `<input id="PASSWORD">`:

```
document.getElementById('PASSWORD').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if (document.getElementById('PASSWORD').value === '') return;
    if (e.which === 13) validatePass();
    // e.which === 13 means enter key is pressed.
});
```

Using `addEventListener` is the preferred way because it does not override other functions bind to `onkeydown` event.

Comment: You probably also want to attach the listener only to the `input` element. Otherwise this will be triggered even if the user is not entering the password.

Comment: @schroffl the listener should be attached to `document` instead of `input` otherwise it will not trigger if input is not focused. Just add a line to make sure targeted `input` is not empty will do.

Comment: But if the user is entering the password the element is focused. And if he then hits the enter key it works. Why would he deselect the element and then press it? I don't see a problem with attaching it to the input.

Comment: how do i attach the listener to the input listener? because it works if no password is typed, but as soon as any other key is pressed it doesn´t function

Comment: @schroffl he might wander off the password field after filling in. it's a possibility.

Comment: @questionador updated the code. you should know how to amend and edit it from here on.

Comment: @YongQuan Sure, but if he wanders off and intends to press the enter key on another element, `validatePass` would also be called. Even if he only wanted to open a dropdown (or whatever there might be on a page). So I would still argue that it's more intiutive to attach it to the input. We could probably continue this discussion, because in the end it depends on a lot more factors. I guess you can use whatever floats your boat ^^

Comment: @schroffl cheers. whatever solves the problem is the solution. both with respective pros and cons (y)  <-- facebook like icon fyi

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for JavaScript would be to add `type="submit"` to the HTML. Most browsers bind that with Enter by default.

Example:
`<button type="submit" onclick="validatePass()>LOGIN</button>`

Answer (score 0):

First, lets make a method to read the enter key that will call your login method

```
function inputKeyUp(e) {
e.which = e.which || e.keyCode;
if (e.which == 13) {
    validatePass();
}
```

}

next, lets call that method in the correct spot in the HTML

```
 <input id='PASSWORD' type='PASSWORD'  onkeyup="inputKeyUp(event)" />
```

And that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
onkeyup = fun1(e) 
in password textbox add this event
in script
fun1(e){
if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13){
       validatePass();
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you'll add short explanations in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete solution look below (changed the login link to black so you can see it):

```js
function validatePass() {
  if (document.getElementById("PASSWORD").value == 'pkmass1725') {
    // do something if the password was correct
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Password errada! Tente de novo.');
    return false;
  }
}

function validateOnEnter(event) {
  var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) { // enter pressed then invoke the validation method
    validatePass();
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image:url(images/IMG_Log_In_teste.jpg);width:1490px;height:243px;color:black;font-size:20px;">
  <br></br>
  <a href="#" onclick="return validatePass()">
    <div class="cities">
      <font color="black">                            
                LOGIN
            </font>
    </div>
  </a>
  <br></br>
  <input id='PASSWORD' type='PASSWORD' onkeypress="validateOnEnter(event)" />
  <a href="#" onclick="return validatePass()"></a>
  <br></br>
</div>
```

Comment: the snippet doesn´t work. when you introduce the correct password the enter key just validates but nothing happens