# How to trigger an onclick event from the console?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this [webpage](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g293913-d1879542-Reviews-W_Taipei-Taipei.html). I would like to pass a JS command to in the console to select "All languages".

[image]

The button is an input with `onchange="widgetEvCall('handlers.updateFilter', event, this);`

This is the complete chunk of html for the botton:

```
<input id="filters_detail_language_filterLang_ALL" type="radio" name="filters_detail_language_filterLang_0" value="ALL" onchange="widgetEvCall('handlers.updateFilter', event, this);">
```

I would like to use the `handlers.updateFilter` function to pass the id of the filter I want to select (`id="filters_detail_language_filterLang_ALL"`) and "simulate" that the button is clicked runnig `handlers.updateFilter` in the chrome console.

Comment: Perhaps not an exact duplicate, but the answers to this question should also answer yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Comment: thanks `document.getElementById("filters_detail_language_filterLang_ALL").click()` worked