# Triggering submit button with Enter keypress event and mouse click

Tags: javascript, submit, keypress, addeventlistener, enter

I am a total beginner and am learning front-end using a "just do it" and project-focus route.

*My web app will essentially work similar to that of a to-do list.*

I assume it is because I have "getElementById" twice for the same element.

**This works initially:**

```
// add idea to list button

document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener("submitIdea", submitIdea);

function submitIdea() {
    var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('anIdea')[0];
    var enterIdea = document.getElementById('enterIdea');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('class', enterIdea.value);            
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(enterIdea.value));
    ul.prepend(li);
    li.contentEditable = 'true';
};
```

**But then, when I add this code, I am unable to write anything at all in my input box:**

```
// use enter key to submit new li item

document.getElementById("enterIdea").addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
    }
});
```

These are the resources I used:

- https://memorynotfound.com/dynamically-addremove-items-list-javascript/
- [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is ok in general

```
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("anIdea")[0];
  var enterIdea = document.getElementById("enterIdea");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute('class', enterIdea.value);
  li.contentEditable = "true";
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(enterIdea.value));
  ul.prepend(li);
});

document.getElementById("enterIdea").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, but the inputted text doesn't remain appended to the list that it was added to. I am also getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: submitIdea is not defined" error in the console log.

Comment: I am truly at a loss. The code partially works. When I mouse click and press the enter key, the submit button now captures the text, but inputs it and then seems to refresh the page at the same time, so it is like a flicker, to put it imaginatively. Also, when I use the enter key, it seems to flicker two new list elements, rather than one when I mouse click the button.

Comment: P.S. Here is my HTML:    

<div class="addIdea">
    <div class="addIdeaBar">
     <form id="formAddIdea" name="formAddIdea">
      <input id="enterIdea" placeholder="Add an idea" type="text"></input>
      <button id="btnSubmit" type:"button">Submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>


    <ul class="anIdea"/>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to "click" the button with javascript, simply call the desired function on the enter key press.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: This still prevents me from inputting text into the input box which is identified as "enterIdea".

Comment: Can you make a code snippet to demonstrate exactly what's going wrong? I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for.