# Javascript to trigger submit when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, enter

I Have a password form and I want the enter key to trigger the submit button but I can't seem to get it to work. I know they can view source to see password this is just for practice example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
        <input id="user" type="text" name="username" 
placeholder="username">
        <input id="pass" type="password" id="pass" name="password">
        <input id="subm"type="button" name="submit" value="submit" 
onclick="checkPswd();">
</form>    
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">  
       function checkPswd(){
        var confirmpassword = "admin";
        var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
        var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

            if(password == confirmpassword){

                window.location.href = "redu.html";

            }else{
                alert('try again');
            }

       };

 </script>    
</html>
```

Comment: I've removed your [tag:java] question tag. Please understand that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages, that questions tags and question titles are the most important parts of your question, and that if either are off, you won't get the correct experts to see your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add id, action, submit type, prevent default and listener. checkout my snippet..

have a nice day!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- add id and action -->
    <form id="example" action="#">
        <input id="user" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
        <input id="pass" type="password" id="pass" name="password">

        <!-- change type to submit -->
        <input id="subm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>    
</body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

//add listener
document.getElementById("example").addEventListener("submit", checkPswd, true);

function checkPswd(){
    var confirmpassword = "admin";
    var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
    var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    if(password == confirmpassword){

        window.location.href = "redu.html";

    }else{
        alert('try again');
    }

    //add prevent default
    event.preventDefault();
};

</script>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `input // submit` with `button` and move the function to the `form` element using `onSubmit`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
        <input id="user" type="text" name="username" 
placeholder="username" onSubmit="checkPswd()">
        <input id="pass" type="password" id="pass" name="password">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>    
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">  
      function checkPswd(){
        var confirmpassword = "admin";
        var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
        var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

            if(password == confirmpassword){

                window.location.href = "redu.html";

            }else{
                alert('try again');
            }

      };

</script>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

inside your form.