# Search by pressing Enter

Tags: javascript

I would like, that when the Enter button is pressed, the application will search a city, the action now is started by pressing the Search button. Below is my code:

```
const ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13;
document.querySelector('#city').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === ENTER_KEY_CODE) {

        var city = $(this).val();
        if (city !== '') {

            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" +
                    "&APPID=bb037310921af67f24ba53f2bad48b1d",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var widget = show(data);

                    $("#show").html(widget);

                    $("#city").val(' ');
                }

            });

        } else {
            $("error").html('Field cant be empty')
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: Use the `submit` event of the form, not a keypress event on the text input or a click event on the button.

Comment: +1 for switching to a `<input type="submit" />` inside the form, then using jQuery's `submit()` as the form submit handler. Better for accessibility and you'll get the onkeypress event too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `keyup` events listener to your `input` element. When the handler is called, simply check the `e.keyCode` to see if it's enter was pressed. If it was, do your thing:

```js
const ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13;
document.querySelector('#textEl').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === ENTER_KEY_CODE) {
    var city = $(this).val();
    var url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${encodeURIComponent(city)}&units=metric&APPID=bb037310921af67f24ba53f2bad48b1d`;
    if (city !== '') {
      console.log(`Make ajax call to ${url}`);
      //Make your AJAX call here
    } else {
      console.log('City cannot be blank!');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textEl" type="text" />
<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submitWeather').addEventListener('keyup',function (e) {
if (e.keyCode ===13){
        var city = $("#city").val();
        if (city !== '') {

            $.ajax({

Comment: I an add this code, but it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: I updated the code. I think this should help you out. Let me know.

Comment: I have this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener'"

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: The problem was in HTML...now I add <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: But now button "Search" doesn't work, can I make any changes, that be available two ways to search (by click of mouse and click Enter button?

Comment: If the code isn't working I can take a look, if you post all the relevant HTML too.

Comment: And what about this? But now button "Search" doesn't work, can I make any changes, that be available two ways to search (by click of mouse and click Enter button? –

Comment: Yes, you can definitely make the search available 2 ways. Just add a click listener to the  "Search" button via `addEventListener('click', someFunc)` where `someFunc` is your search function. Let me know if that doesnt make sense to you.

Comment: It doesnt make sense for me( Can you please change the code with this function

Answer (score 0):

This a sample code please use this a reference code.

**HTML code**

```
<input id="InputEnter" >
```

**Javascript code**

```
var input = document.getElementById("InputEnter");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   $(document).ready(function () {

$('#submitWeather').click(function () {

    var city = $("#city").val();
    if (city !== '') {

        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" +
                "&APPID=bb037310921af67f24ba53f2bad48b1d",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var widget = show(data);

                $("#show").html(widget);

                $("#city").val(' ');
            }
  }
});
```

Comment: How I an add this code in my JS? What I need to change?

Comment: Once try the edited code and we will discuss further

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I assume that your ajax request is correct.

```
document.querySelector('#submitWeather').addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
        if(e.which === 13){
            // your ajax request
        }
    })
```