# Javascript triger an Enter key without actually press the Enter key when onload page for search input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating an onload page that contain search input, and the value is generated from url

```
http://localhost/example?i%search%this
```

in the onload page i create this =

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
// this is where i put the input search that needs Enter to active search
<input type="text" class="form-control searchable-input floatL value-not-empty" placeholder="Search Badan Usaha" name="s545858fe" id="s545858fe">
</body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var newURL = window.location.search.substr(1);
    var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(newURL);
    document.getElementById("s545858fe").value = uri_dec;
}
</script>
```

my actual results is that i get "i search this" text in my input search, but its not execute the search because the search need enter key to execute

Comment: Is your `input` element inside a `form`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box)

Comment: actually my input page is a form control search Nick, so this is the search control that filter the data grid i have

Comment: do you want to execute some code when `enter` key is pressed while input field is in focus?

Comment: no @Yousaf, i just want to triger enter key without actually press the enter key so that my search input is executed

Comment: so you want to execute code whenever you type something inside input field?

Comment: @Yousaf No, i want to execute serach whenever the page is onload

Comment: @dhilt its not the same, i want to trigger an Enter key when javascript onoad. NOT press the enter key

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an Enter keypress inside the `<input>` by creating a [`KeyboardEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) and then dispatching the event:

```js
const entry = document.getElementById('s545858fe');

entry.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    console.log('Keypress in entry with value: ' + this.value);
}, false);

function myFunction() {
    const evt = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {});

    entry.focus();
    entry.value = "new value";
    entry.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
<input type="text" class="form-control searchable-input floatL value-not-empty" placeholder="Search Badan Usaha" name="s545858fe" id="s545858fe">
</body>
```

Comment: this dispatchEvent actually works but only if i delete the 
    function myFunction() {}
but when i delete it, its not reworking when i reload the page. the value is still the old value. can you give me pointer

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean it only works if you delete the function? Can you update your code?