# How do I make Enter affect a specific submit button when I have more than one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a question about having two submit buttons on a single form (the two buttons are below). I currently have two buttons, one to submit the login data and attempt to validate the login by running a database query, and the other to bring the user to a page to generate a random string and set it as their new password.

I want to be able to make it so that when I hit enter, the second button (the login process button) is triggered, where it is currently the initial button that is done. I have tried turning the first button from an input to a normal button tag, but the issue still persists. Brief snippet of the buttons below, if the full form would be helpful I can edit it in.

I tried some solutions I found online such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box), but I couldn't get it working - maybe I'm just a bit stupid!

Any and all help is fully appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="field">
    <p class="control">
      <!-- if clicked, brings user to reset password-->
      <input type='submit' class="button is-danger" id='loginRequest' value="Forgot Password" formaction="resetpassword.php">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="field">
    <p class="control">
      <!-- if clicked, posts info and attempts to validate login through database-->
      <input type='submit' class="button is-primary" id='loginRequest' value="Login" name="requestlogin">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest making the button which opens the password generation page in to a standard button, as it has nothing to do with the form content. This solves your problem by proxy

Comment: It is my dim understanding that `submit` buttons do, and `button` buttons don't.

Comment: Thanks both for your responses - unfortunately my server has gone down so cannot attempt to fix it and report back immediately! :)

Comment: Thanks, that fixes my issue!