# Enter key function with Java

Tags: javascript

I have a search `input` and I want to enter the values of the buttons by clicking on them to enter and search.
Values are entered with the function, but the search is not performed. (Actually, I want the `Enter` key function to be executed after entering the words)

```js
function test(a) {
  document.getElementById("dp").value = a
}
```

```html
search : <input id="dp"><br>
<button  onclick="test(this.innerHTML)">test</button>
<button  onclick="test(this.innerHTML)">test2</button>
<button  onclick="test(this.innerHTML)">test3</button>
<button  onclick="test(this.innerHTML)">test4</button>
```

Comment: "but the search is not performed" <= what does that mean?

Comment: I want the Enter key function to be executed after entering the words

Comment: That is, the search should be done @Taplar

Comment: Is that a form submit, or an ajax call due to an event handler.  What does that mean?

Comment: 1) search where/how
2) you need to add event listener on submit and on click and write your logic there

Comment: For the enter key part read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution :
`  var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;

$("#dp").trigger(e);
`