# How to call function on enter key press with html

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have this markup:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="...">
<button type="button" onclick="newInput();">Enter</button>
```

### And I want to know how to call my function by *typing* `enter` instead of having to actually press the button?

How could you do this?

Edit: this can be done with JS using event listeners but I want to know if you can call the function in pure HTML.

Comment: In particular, this answer: [Trigger a button click with JavaScript on the Enter key in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155272)

Comment: If your input, and button, are inside a form that's the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a "submit" event listener on your form. You have to call preventDefault() on the event, in your function, so the default behaviour of the form submitting is avoided.

Please see snippet below

```js
function newInput(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Function called');
}

// The form element
var form = document.getElementById("submitForm");

// Attach event listener
form.addEventListener("submit", newInput, true);
```

```html
<form id="submitForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="...">
    <button type="submit">Enter</button>
<form>
```

EDIT : Regarding your edit, you can also use the "onsubmit" attribute on the form element :

```js
function newInput(){
  alert('Function called');
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="newInput()" id="submitForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="...">
<button type="submit">Enter</button>
<form>
```