# HTML Search button not searching when hitting enter

Tags: html, css

I have implemented a search button onto my index.html but every time I hit enter on a search the page just refreshes and doesn't search the correct term or similar terms.

**INDEX.HTML SEARCH CODE**

```
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Content...">
    </form>
```

**CSS snippet**

```
/*SEARCH BAR - MAIN PAGE - START--------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 1.5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  background-image: 'searchicon.png';
  background-position: 10px 10px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
/*SEARCH BAR END--------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
}
```

Thank you, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: search wont work until you add some `javascript` code in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the javascript preventing the actual form submission.

```js
document.getElementById('searchForm')
  .addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    // Prevent the default form submission
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // Perform your search logic here,
    // such as fetching search results or updating the page content
    console.log('Searching for:', this.elements.search.value);
  });
```

```html
<form id="searchForm" action="/your-search-endpoint" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Content...">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of a form is to refresh the page on submit. You can either use an action attribute to specify where the form data should be sent for processing or add a JavaScript event listener to listen for form submission and prevent the page from refreshing like this;

1- Specify `action` attribute

```
<form action="/processForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Content...">
</form>
```

2- Use `Javascript` Function

```
<form onsubmit="handleSearch(event)">
 <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Content...">
</form>

<script>
  function handleSearch(event) {
    // Prevent the default form submission
    event.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
```